# Britt id questions

Tags: barcode-scanner

```
@

ANSI 636023090102ID00410313ZO03540049IDDBA10062026
DCSCOLWELL
DACBRITTNEY
DADPATRICIA
DBD12222023
DBB10061993
DBC2
DAYHAZ
DAU065 in
DAG3738 TYLOR DR
DAICOLUMBUS
DAJOH
DAK432320000  
DAQTQ962089
DCF018673818
DCGUSA
DDEN
DDFN
DDGN
DAZBRO
DCIOHIO
DCJ
DCU
DCE3
DDAN
DDB07012018
DDC
DAW140
DDL
DCA
DCB
DCD
DAH
DCKC95114000
DCN
DCO
DAX063
DDH
DDI
DDJ
DDK

ZOZOAN
ZOBN
ZOE
ZOC
ZOD
ZOF
ZOG
ZOH
ZOI
ZOK
ZOL
```

Trying to understand what this is and why the barcode on the back of my id is scanning  into the code of this doesn't make much sense please help if I have a fradulant id an if they remade my id so it won't scan properly online I just received it today